# How can I type "\" (backslash) via remote desktop with a Norwegian, Danish or Swedish keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, remote-desktop

I am running Remote Desktop to connect from my MacBook Air with Yosemite to a Windows computer running Windows 8.1.

Both my Mac and the Windows computer is configured with Norwegian keyboard layout.
It seems "\" backslash is impossible to input in this keyboard configuration. I would guess it's the same for Danish and Swedish keyboards.

Is there a way to easily input this character in RDP for Mac using this keyboard layout?

(I would be willing to map some key combination if that's possible, but I don't want to switch to some other keyboard layout, since I need to input Norwegian characters now and then)

Comment: So neither option+shift+7 nor the topmost rightmost key work?

Comment: No, none of these work in an RDP session

Comment: The irritating thing about RDP is you cannot 'pre-map', you have to find the key that actually will work for Windows. UK keyboard, Mac is 3 keys right of L ; '  Windows is very bottom-left, next to z

Comment: I do not use Norwegian keyboard therefore my the question is "If", If you use the "keyboard viewer" press shit+alt then mouse click on the backslash \ that should work

Comment: What worked for me was left command plus * (or ') (the key exactly left of the enter key on a macbook pro). it may be depending on having citrix receiver in between, that also has some settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was actually a bug in Remote Desktop for OS X, and has been fixed in 8.0.15, which was released a few days ago. Now the keyboard works completely as expected with both my Mac and the Windows computer configured with Norwegian keyboard layout.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try Alt + ?. It is working for me with Swedish Keyboard.

Comment: Alt gr + ? is working for me

Comment: AltGr `+` is what worked for me in VMWare Fusion with a Finnish keyboard. The question mark is shift `+` so it's the same key as what is probably being recommended here, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

When you are in the Windows RDP app you should be able to type in the Alt-Code for "\" (Alt-92) no matter which input source you have set. It's not ideal, but should get the job done!

Simply hold down the option/alt key and type 92.

For the record the Alt-Codes don't work in Mac apps.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code

You can find a full list of Alt-Codes at [alt-codes.net](http://www.alt-codes.net/)

Comment: This obviously requires the remote system to be Windows. While that's true in the OP's case, it would be nice to have a solution which works when connecting to Linux hosts etc too.

Answer (score 1):

I use two languages, English and Romanian, and the keyboard is Romanian. From the language menu in the menu bar, you can click on the flag (if you dont't see it, just check System Preferences, Keyboard, Input Sources > Show Input menu in menu bar) and select Show keyboard viewer.

If you press CMD, Alt or fn, some keys from the keyboard viewer will change. Locate the "\" character in the viewer, it must show up when pressing one of the keys mentioned above. Then, to type the character, simple press the corresponding CMD/ALT/fn key + the key from the keyboard that changed beforehand.

Also check this Apple Support page: [OS X Yosemite: Use the Keyboard Viewer](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18449)

Answer (score 1):

shift+alt+7 under swedish pro keyboard layout

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround (which I'd love to have something better than) I've found that finding an existing backslash and doing a copy/paste of it to the new location works, but is obviously very clunky and not a permanent fix.

Answer (score 0):

a quick workaround is to just copy and paste from your local machine. I found however CTRL+ALT+~ produces the backslash quickly

Comment: With which keyboard layout? The `~` character is a dead key which itself requires modifier keys to produce on Scandinavian keyboards.

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing Shift twice, the \ key then seems to work in RDP

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Option</kbd> <kbd>8</kbd> did the trick on French Keyboard Layout (OS X and Remote Windows)

Answer (score -1):

ctrl-alt-+ works for me, Swedish keyboard

Answer (score -1):

shift+Insert Key

for back slash key on remote machines "\"

Comment: Macs don't have an Insert key.